# Error compiling file.y.c in Bison syntax analysis

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to compile and run a Bison file and I used the following commands in the Linux terminal:

```
bison -d comp.y
mv comp.tab.h comp.h
mv comp.tab.c comp.y.c
flex fonte.l
mv lex.yy.c fonte.lex.c
gcc -g -c fonte.lex.c -o fonte.lex.o
gcc -g -c comp.y.c -o comp.y.o
```

All work without problems. But when I run the latter (`gcc -g -c comp.y.c -o comp.y.o`), it generates the following errors:

````
comp.tab.c:1278:16: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yylex’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
comp.y:22:22: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yyerror’; did you mean ‘yyerrok’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   22 | FECHA_CHAVE | error {yyerrok("erro no inicio", linhas); };
      |                      ^~~~~~~
      |                      yyerrok
comp.y: In function ‘yyerror’:
comp.y:61:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcmp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   61 | if(strcmp(str,"syntax error")==0){
      |    ^~~~~~
comp.y: At top level:
comp.y:72:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
   72 | int main (int argc, char **argv )```
````

I've tried to see some solutions on the internet, but nothing really worked. Here is my file comp.y:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
extern int linhas;
extern int erros;
int yylex(void);
%}

%token ASPAS ABRE_PARENTESIS FECHA_PARENTESIS
%token ABRE_CHAVE FECHA_CHAVE SEPARADOR VIRGULA
FLOAT INT PRINTF VOID DOUBLE LONG MAIN
%token IDENTIFICADOR INTEIRO REAL OPERADOR
COMPARADORES NEGACAO IGUAL
%token ATRIBUICAO
%start Programa_principal

%%

//programa principal
Programa_principal: MAIN ABRE_PARENTESIS
FECHA_PARENTESIS ABRE_CHAVE Comandos
FECHA_CHAVE | error {yyerrok("erro no inicio", linhas); };

Comandos: Comando Comandos | Comando ;

Comando: Declaracao | Atribuicao | Print | error {yyerror("erro de comando",linhas); };

Declaracao: Tipo Decl SEPARADOR;

Tipo: INT | FLOAT | DOUBLE | LONG INT ;

Decl: LISTA_VAR ;

LISTA_VAR: IDENTIFICADOR Atribui_valor VIRGULA LISTA_VAR | IDENTIFICADOR Atribui_valor;

Atribui_valor: IGUAL Num | ;

Num: INTEIRO | REAL ;


Atribuicao: IDENTIFICADOR IGUAL Exp SEPARADOR ;

Exp: INT x | FLOAT x | Num x | IDENTIFICADOR x;

x: OPERADOR Exp | ;

//Sintaxe de impressão
Print: PRINTF ABRE_PARENTESIS ASPAS
Qualquer_palavra ASPAS FECHA_PARENTESIS
SEPARADOR;

Qualquer_palavra: IDENTIFICADOR y;

y: IDENTIFICADOR y | ;

%%

FILE *yyin;

int yyerror(char *str, int num_linha) {
if(strcmp(str,"syntax error")==0){
erros++;
printf("Erro sintático\n");
}
else
{
printf("O erro aparece próximo à linha %d\n",num_linha);//Exibe a linha do erro
}
return erros;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv )
{
++argv, --argc; //desconsidera o nome do programa
if ( argc > 0 )
yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
else
{
puts("Falha ao abrir arquivo, nome incorreto ou não especificado. Digite o comando novamente.");

exit(0);
}
do {

yyparse();

} while (!feof(yyin));
if(erros==0)
puts("Análise concluída com sucesso");
}
```

Previously it was just "main" so I changed it to "int main". I also put an int yylex(); at the top of the `comp.y` file, but neither of the 2 solved any of the problems.

Comment: If you made those changes to `comp.y` and the corresponding errors persist, it probably means you didn't recompile the correct file. You should use some kind of build script rather than a complicated series of commands. (You could simplify the commands by using the `-o` options of bison and flex. But you should still use a build script.) I don't understand the motivation for the use of `strcmp` in `yyerror`, but if you are going to use it you will need to `#include <string.h>`. And `yyerror` needs to be declared in the prologue.

Comment: Isn't there just a typo and `yyerrok` should be `yyerror`?